# git reset causes web.config not to be readable

Tags: .net, git, visual-studio, iis, web-config

I've managed to get my codebase/repository/machine into a state where `git reset --hard` breaks my code and closing/re-opening the sln in VS fixes it.

Specifically:

- Open the Code base

  - Rebuild & Run
  - Site runs fine
- run `git reset --hard`

  - Rebuild & Run
  - Site fails with <Error_below>
- Close and then re-open VS

  - Rebuild & Run
  - Site runs fine
- run `git reset --hard`

  - Rebuild & Run
  - Site fails with
- Rinse, Repeat, ad nauseum.

Error Details:

- HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
- Error Code: 0x80070003
- Error Message: Cannot read configuration file
- Config File      \?\C:\Work\Project Source code Folder\Website\web.config

Obviously I've checked that the config file is present, in the correct place, and is well-formed (no unclosed tags, etc.) at all points.

My First guess was file permissions but neither `chmod web.config 777`, nor Window permissions > Everyone -> Full Access made any difference that I could tell (possible that I miss-applied them, though?)

Comment: Before you run `git --reset hard`, what does `git status -sb` report?

Comment: Oddly 80070003 is 'path not found', not 'file not found'. Probably worth running [process monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) in the background to see if there are any other failures or better error codes to investigate. Apart from that maybe VS is fixing something in the file - AtnHn's suggestion - although I didn't think line endings mattered in web.config, or maybe it's correcting IIS bindings that the git reset has somehow broken.